# How would I figure out how many bills it takes to reach a certain listed monetary value

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, counter

In Java:

Figure out how many bills it takes to reach certain monetary value:

Example:

bill1 = 100

bill2 = 50

bill3 = 20

bill4 = 10

bill5 = 5

bill6 = 1

Total value: 374

the result returned should be:

Bill1: 3

Bill2: 1

Bill3: 1

Bill4: 0

Bill5: 0

Bill6: 4

It should work for whatever number I have for bills as well as whatever value I choose.

Comment: Google is your friend. [Read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). After you're done reading, get coins of various denominations, pick a price point, pick an amount tendered and play around until you understand the problem. Code is a lot easier to write when you know what you're actually trying to solve.

Comment: What did you try and what are you struggling with? Please do your homework and ask when stuck or if you don't understand something https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Best way to say this is: my professor hasn't taught us the language yet and presented this problem to us and I got curious as to how one would do it, but no, it wasn't homework and I struggled using google because I absolutely did not understand what I read hence why I came here to see what the coded out response would be, although I didn't need it for anything anytime soon.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the modulo `%` operator, and how Java handles division.

```
int input = 374;
int remainder = input;

int billOnes = remainder / 100;
remainder = remainder % 100; //This gives back 74, as the result is 3 remainder 74

int billTwos = remainder / 50;
remainder = remainder % 50;

int billThrees = remainder / 20;
etc...
```

You can store the bill values in separate variables / array as well.